# Resolve command in WPF. what is the resolve word?

Tags: wpf, xaml

Can someone explain this XAML statement, particularly what is the `Resolve`?

```
<MenuItem Header="_Load File" Command="{Resolve {Type Commands:LoadFile}}" />
```

This snippet was taken from `NHprof.exe` `MainMenu.xaml` file, using reflector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is in {}, this is a MarkupExtension. In this case it is a custom extension called ResolveExtension (by convention, the Extension suffix is not needed). So look in the code for the class ResolveExtension.

Comment: Thanks, find it. `Caliburn.PresentationFramework.ResolveExtension`.